# Are temporary hp added to normal hp to determine power word spells' effects?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, temporary-hit-points

I found in a similar topic for [dnd-5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) while searching for an answer, and in that game it appears that a creature's temporary hp and its normal hp are *not* added together for determining the effects of spells like the various *power word* spells.

Are the rules for temporary hp in this regard different in [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, Temporary HP count for such effects

The rules on temporary HP in 3.5 are not as explicitly defined as in 5e, but they do mention how temporary hit points work - by temporarily changing your actual hit point total:

> When a character gains temporary hit points, note his current hit point total. When the temporary hit points go away the character’s hit points drop to his current hit point total.

(From the SRD, section Injury and Death)

In other words, your "current hit point total" was actually higher while the temporary hit points were in effect. It is not a seperate, distinct pool, like it is in 5th edition.

Power Word spells only reference "hit points", with no special mention of temporary HP. This is the same wording as the rules on temporary HP above, so Power Word spells look at the same, increased amount of hit points.